# Add Image to C# DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

> As I know The DataGridView control and its related classes are
>   designed to be a flexible, extensible system for displaying and
>   editing tabular data.  And We can add an Image control in a column of
>   DataGridView. Setting the column Image property results in that image
>   being displayed by default for all the cells in that column. The
>   following C# program shows how to add a Image in column of a
>   DataGridView control.

Can any one give me a example to add Image to C# DataGridView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hope this will help

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Product ID";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Product Name";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Product Price";

    string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "2", "Product 2", "2000" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "3", "Product 3", "3000" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    row = new string[] { "4", "Product 4", "4000" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

    DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    Image image = Image.FromFile("Image Path");
    img.Image = image;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
    img.HeaderText = "Image";
    img.Name = "img";

}
```